# how to print the first occurence of a column matching more than once with awk

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a log_file with all my backups and a column with value yes means it won't be deleted by the retention policy (Preserved).  there could be 1 or more rows having that preserved column = yes for a specific vmname.

My input is :

```
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210105-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210202-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210302-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210406-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2146     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2153     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2148     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2122     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210406-2122 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2105     == execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2106     == execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2106     == execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2105     == execnet.0-FULL-20210406-2105 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210106   ==     0200     == Prtgadmin.0-FULL-20210106-0200 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2216     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2227     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2152     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210406-2152 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2236     == wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2249     == wwwp.0-FULL-20210202-2249 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2259     == wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2314     == wwws.0-FULL-20210202-2314 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2259     == webhost.0-FULL-20210105-2259 ==  YES
```

My desired output is to print the n-1 oldest matches (top n-1)

```
ASR-FULL-20210105-2100        
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100         
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100         
DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146     
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153     
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148     
execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105  
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106   
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106   
sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216   
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227   
wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236     
wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259
```

I can so far have the below result by running the below awk commands but It shows the most recent matches instead. I'd also like to have one awk command ideally .
The year filter is not that important .

```
# cat bkp_list.log| grep -E '*2021.*YES'| awk -F[==-] 'cnt[$8]++{if (cnt[$8]>1) print prev=$0;next}' |awk -F[==] '{print $8}'
```

```
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100
ASR-FULL-20210406-2100
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148
DNS10_7-FULL-20210406-2122
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210406-2105
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227
sandbox.0-FULL-20210406-2152
wwwp.0-FULL-20210202-2249
wwws.0-FULL-20210202-2314
```

Thank you

Comment: man, why u dont have the line  == ASR-FULL-20210105-2100 ==  YES ?¿? I don't get the logic

Comment: it is extracted from a another backup tool command to list the list of backups . sorry not on me

Comment: Hi @ed-morton , thank you . Yes you are right, I meant 2 contiguous '='  in my filter . will use your suggestion meanwhile .

Comment: @anubhava  what do you mean ? it's in ther first line . == ASR-FULL-20210105-2100 ==

Comment: sorry I meant n-1 oldet matches (n-1 top matches)  I have edited the OP.
And thank you all for the help.
and no I never implied anyone should try to figure it out implicitly. It is my mistake on the first version of the post and correction has been added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print all but last match of a substring of `$8` you may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '
$NF != "YES" {next}
{
   s = $8
   sub(/-FULL-.*/, "", s)
}
s == ps {
   print pval
}
{
   ps = s
   pval = $8
}' file

ASR-FULL-20210105-2100
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100
DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148
execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106
sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227
wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236
wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259
```

Or one liner:

```sh
awk '$NF != "YES"{next} {s=$8; sub(/-FULL-.*/, "", s)} s == ps {print pval} {ps = s; pval=$8}' file
```

Comment: awesome  @anubhava. I am trying it in one line, I hope It can be run as a one liner

Comment: `awk '!/2021.*YES/ {next} {s=$8; sub(/-FULL-.*/, "", s)} s == ps {print pval} {ps = s; pval=$8}' file` is one liner

Comment: excellent that's exactly what I wanted .  you add one without  the 2021 as a variant . I'll put it as valid answer . thank you so much  
awk '!/.*YES/ {next} {s=$8; sub(/-FULL-.*/, "", s)} s == ps {print pval} {ps = s; pval=$8}'

Comment: Much appreciated Sir !!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter on the column with the YES, you can do it with the contitional expressions before blocks

```
$ cat file
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210105-2100 ==  NO
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210202-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210302-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2100     == ASR-FULL-20210406-2100 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2146     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2153     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2148     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2122     == DNS10_7-FULL-20210406-2122 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2105     == execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2106     == execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210302   ==     2106     == execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2105     == execnet.0-FULL-20210406-2105 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210106   ==     0200     == Prtgadmin.0-FULL-20210106-0200 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2216     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2227     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210406   ==     2152     == sandbox.0-FULL-20210406-2152 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2236     == wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2249     == wwwp.0-FULL-20210202-2249 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2259     == wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210202   ==     2314     == wwws.0-FULL-20210202-2314 ==  YES
=    FULL     ==   20210105   ==     2259     == webhost.0-FULL-20210105-2259 ==  YES
```

```
$ awk ' $NF == "YES" { print $(NF-2) }' file
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100
ASR-FULL-20210406-2100
DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148
DNS10_7-FULL-20210406-2122
execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210406-2105
Prtgadmin.0-FULL-20210106-0200
sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227
sandbox.0-FULL-20210406-2152
wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236
wwwp.0-FULL-20210202-2249
wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259
wwws.0-FULL-20210202-2314
webhost.0-FULL-20210105-2259
```

```
$ awk ' $NF == "NO" { print $(NF-2) }' file
ASR-FULL-20210105-2100
$
```

** note I changed the first line YES to NO to check the correct behaviour

Anyway, if u need to do any other special filtering, like checking the year, please specify

Comment: The year is not that important really. I think your approach is good as I removed the need for the awk and grep part of my OP command . but I still need to show all but the last occurrence for each vm-FULL-*.   (i.e 2 previous out of 3)
we're almost there :)

```
# awk ' $NF == "YES" { print $(NF-2) }'  file.log |awk -F[==-] 'cnt[$1]++{if (cnt[$1]>1) print prev=$0;next}' 
```

Comment: btw , the previous cnt syntax didn't print the top n-1 occurrences . So I'm not there yet it seems

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ tac file | awk '$NF=="YES" && seen[gensub(/-.*/,"",1,$8)]++{print $8}' | tac
ASR-FULL-20210105-2100
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100
DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148
execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106
sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227
wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236
wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259
```

or with any awk:

```
$ tac file | awk '$NF!="YES"{next} {k=$8; sub(/-.*/,"",k)} seen[k]++{print $8}' | tac
ASR-FULL-20210105-2100
ASR-FULL-20210202-2100
ASR-FULL-20210302-2100
DNS10_7-FULL-20210105-2146
DNS10_7-FULL-20210202-2153
DNS10_7-FULL-20210302-2148
execnet.0-FULL-20210105-2105
execnet.0-FULL-20210202-2106
execnet.0-FULL-20210302-2106
sandbox.0-FULL-20210105-2216
sandbox.0-FULL-20210202-2227
wwwp.0-FULL-20210105-2236
wwws.0-FULL-20210105-2259
```